# How to make insert operation using MySqlDataAdapter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I am able to perform insert using the code which I've made comments here. How to achieve the same using MySqlDataAdapter ? The code I've written isn't working.

```
string sid, sname;
            sid = Request.QueryString["StudentId"].ToString();
            sname = Request.QueryString["StudentName"].ToString();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("insert into tblStudent (StudentId, StudentName) values ('" + sid.ToString() + "', '" + sname.ToString() + "')", con);
          //  con.Open();
        //    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
      //      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblStudent (StudentId, StudentName) values('" + sid.ToString() + "', '" + sname.ToString() + "')";
  //          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//            con.Close();
```

Help with suggestions.

Comment: If you want to just insert a record work with the MySqlCommand directly. MySqlDataAdapter is overkill for that and more difficult to use for this task alone

Comment: `MySqlDataAdapter` is more for filling a `Dataset`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection and bobby tables likes this kind of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You can use a DataAdapter also for Insert, Update and Delete actions, but you first need to fill a DataTable, add the new record to the datatable and finally call Update. Not worth the effort if you just need to insert a single record

Comment: But writing MySqlAdapter is much easier right @Steve

Comment: But it has a lot of overhead that you don't really need to insert a single record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a single record you could simply use the MySqlCommand instead of a MySqlDataAdapter.  MySqlDataAdapter has many functionality and allows you to execute Insert, Update and Delete actions on your data but you first need to reach the server to fill a DataTable, then add a new record to the datatable and finally call Update. Not worth the effort if you just need to insert a single record

However if you really want to try to use an DataAdapter then you need this code

```
string sid, sname;
sid = Request.QueryString["StudentId"].ToString();
sname = Request.QueryString["StudentName"].ToString();
string selectText = "SELECT studentID, StudentName FROM tblStudent WHERE 1=0";
using(MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectText, con))
{
     MySqlCommandBuilder bd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);
     // This is important, because Update will work only on rows
     // present in the DataTable whose RowState is Added, Modified or Deleted
     dt.Rows.Add(sid, sname);
     da.Update(dt);
}
```

Comment: just to experiment. Thank you :)